# How to refer to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not sure if the title to this question is correct.

We have to create two classes.

In first class, we sharing position to other class. In second class we getting position about that, e.g.
I am sure that my mistake lies somewhere in the GameObject Enemy.

Are you able to help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurretAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Range = 5f;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public GameObject Bullet;
    float countdown = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        float DistanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Enemy.transform.position);

            if (DistanceToEnemy < Range)
            {
                if (countdown<=0)
                {               
                    Shoot();
                    countdown = 2;
                }                             
            }
       There i have an error// FindObjectOfType<BulletAI>().Target(Enemy);
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
       
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, Range);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object is an instance of a class (Thanks to DiplomacyNotWar).
We may think of a class as the general idea or blueprint, and the object as the actual 'material' realizaton of said class.
What is happening in your case is that you're now editing the blueprint. You have not instantiated a Turret. In Java, we'd do something like this:

```
Turret turret1 = new Turret("Conga");
Turret turret2 = new Turret("Bonga");
```

Hope this makes sense.

I see that you have 2 GameObject entities that have not been *initialized*. We must initiazlied them, otherwise they have a default value of NULL or some such as pet c# would dictate.

Comment: i messed up. it is the other way around

Comment: The example I always go to in this situation is that a class is like a car model: it's not any specific car, it's just the design and specs. The cars you see on the road are the instances.

Comment: indeed that is a good way to think about it.